# How to pass independent variable as parameter to lmfit minimize

Tags: python, minimize, minimization, lmfit

I am new to this statistical thing.

So I have a data set y = f(x) for some values of x. I want to fit this data to a `func` so that for every point in `y` I can calculate the value of `x`.

suppose the model I want to fit is something like

```py
def func(x,a,b,c):
    return a+b*x/c
```

now to use minimize function, i've to define parameters:

```py
params = Parameters()
params.add('a' , value = 10)
params.add('b' , value = 1)
params.add('c' , value = 2)
```

```py
result = minimize(func, param, arg=(x, y))
```

My question is, what if I want to make my `x` variable as parameter and pass it as parameter.

Basically when I pass `x` as variable i am passing an array which corresponds to specific points in my data set. However I want to find use `x` as a parameter because I want to find value of `x` for certain points of data `y`.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters and fitting variables are scalar floating-point numbers. That is to say, they have one value that can take a continuous range of values.

Do you mean that you want every element of `x` to be independently varied in the fit?

It is common to use minimization methods to fit data: find the set of values for the variables (say, your `a`, `b`, and `c`) so that `y - func(x, a, b, c)` is as small as possible.

Your incomplete code snippet (to be clear, it is **always** better to include a complete example) doesn't do that -- it doesn't pass `y` into `func`.

More importantly, you seem to be looking to "find the value of `x` for certain points of data `y`".  That doesn't quite make sense to me.... Maybe clean up and clarify the question?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a one way step.

I achieved it by using `Model` class in `lmfit`

Consider this.

I have model function which I name say: `MF` through which I calculate exact `samples` as of raw data.

I have raw data : `Raw_Data` (say for example coming from sensors)

then I have certain `parameters`. (x, y, z, samples)

Now I consider that samples is an `independent variable`.

My goal is to estimate one of the parameters.

First I have to create a Model class

```
mod = Model (MF, parameters, independant_vars = ['samples']
```

then you set the initial parameters using Parameters() class.

and add init values

```
fit_params = Parameters()
fit_params.add('x', value = 170)
fit_params.add('y', value = 120)
fit_params.add('z', value = 110)
```

Then you fit the model

```
Result - mod.fit(Raw_data, params = fit_params, samples = your_samples)
```

The output is a `dict`.

Comment: Is this an extension of the original question from many months ago? I don't see a question.  I also see a few questionable statements and some things that are probably errors.  It is always better to include a complete, minimal code and ask a clear ad direct question about that.